# Firebase throwing NetworkOnMainThreadException on initialization when onTrimMemory is called

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Some users are experiencing the following error:

```
Fatal Exception: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
       at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1528)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.blockGuardOnNetwork(Platform.java:415)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.shutdownAndFreeSslNative(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:1005)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.close(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:1000)
       at com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocket.closeSocket(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:264)
       at com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocket.close(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:238)
       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection$WSClientTubesock.close(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:132)
       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.close(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:218)
       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.close(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:98)
       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.close(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:107)
       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.interrupt(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:527)
       at com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidPlatform$2.onBackgroundStateChanged(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:131)
       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.notifyBackgroundStateChangeListeners(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.1.0:619)
       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.access$600(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.1.0:103)
       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp$GlobalBackgroundStateListener.onBackgroundStateChanged(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.1.0:979)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BackgroundDetector.onBackgroundStateChanged(Unknown Source:45)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BackgroundDetector.onTrimMemory(Unknown Source:41)
       at android.app.Application.onTrimMemory(Application.java:149)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleTrimMemory(ActivityThread.java:5678)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:213)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.lambda$scheduleTrimMemory$0(ActivityThread.java:1453)
       at android.app.-$$Lambda$ActivityThread$ApplicationThread$tUGFX7CUhzB4Pg5wFd5yeqOnu38.accept(Unknown Source:8)
       at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.doInvoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:258)
       at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.invoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:182)
       at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.OmniFunction.run(OmniFunction.java:77)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:698)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6923)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
```

I couldn't reproduce it yet, but it seems to happen when the device is low on memory and the user has updated the app from a version where `FirebaseApp.setAutomaticResourceManagementEnabled` was set to `false` to a version where this is set to `true`.

The app crashes before it's fully initialized, as we currently call `FirebaseApp.getInstance()` for the first time while inside our `Application.onCreate` method.

Are we doing something wrong here or is this a potential bug in the Firebase SDK?

Comment: This looks like a Firebase bug, as I do not see where your code would be responsible for this crash. Are you on the latest version of the libraries?

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for answering. Yes, I'm using the last version.